# How we can make a special shape in python?

Tags: python

Making a special shape (like rectangular, circle,...) on the honeycomb lattice.

I need to make a shape like rectangular on the honeycomb lattice surface. At first I made this kind of shape. Then I need to add on-site energy for this rectangular. I used as the following:

```
import kwant

latt = kwant.lattice.honeycomb(2)

a, b = latt.sublattices

r=8

t=-1

tp=-0.1

def circle(pos):
    x,y=pos
    z=x**2+y**2
    return z< r**2 and z>4
syst = kwant.Builder()
syst[latt.shape(circle, (2, 2))] = 0
syst[latt.neighbors(1)] = t
return syst
```

But I don't know exactly what is exactly coordinate (2,2) in the above-mentioned expression. Why do we use it and is it the same for other kinds of shapes?

Comment: Please provide more details and the relevant code parts.

Comment: please look at the new example in the above-mentioned code.